# System restore doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-restore

Here is the error message:

> System Restore did not complete successfully. Your computer's system files and settings were not changed.
>
> Details:
>
> System Restore failed while restoring the directory from the restore point.
> Source: AppxStaging
> Destination: %ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps
> An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x80070091)

[image: Screenshot of error message]

What I've tried so far:

- chkdsk /f /r C: (didn't work)
- tried running in safe mode the system restore (didn't work)
- tried with another system restore point (didn't work)

Comment: Do you by chance have a start menu replacement installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me after I updated my Lenovo's drivers and had issues with driver power states. I was able to perform a restore by doing the following:

1. Boot into command line mode (search Advanced Startup in windows settings)
2. `C:`
3. `cd C:\Program Files`
4. `attrib WindowsApps -h` this removed the hidden attribute
5. `rename WindowsApps WindowsApps-renamed`
6. `exit`
7. restore the system to the desired restore point
8. reboot normally or *continue to windows*

When the restore is complete, a previous version of `WindowsApps` will have been restored.

To then go back and delete `WindowsApps-renamed`:

1. <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
2. <kbd>a</kbd> to open an Administrator Command Prompt
3. `cd C:\Program Files`
4. `takeown /f WindowsApps-renamed`
5. `rmdir WindowsApps-renamed /S`

Comment: I got the exact same issue but on another drive D:\WindowsApps
I did the same steps but I got the same error and can't restore. Any ideas?

Comment: @Enrico Is `D:` a network drive? Are system restore points enabled on that drive. Does `Get-ComputerRestorePoint` list any restore points?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. **delete or rename folder WindowsApps then restart system, after this, restore function can be cover.** follow this link step by step to fix this issue.

Windows 10 Version 1607: System restore error 0x80070091 [Fix]
http://borncity.com/win/2017/02/22/windows10-version-1607-system-restore-error-0x80070091/

Here is a thread discussing in Microsoft forum for your reference.

System Restore failed - Source: AppxStaging Error - (0x80070091) 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/93a0d2a2-d9f1-4b57-97b9-0ca30de656aa/system-restore-failed-source-appxstaging-error-0x80070091?forum=win10itproapps

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions ([not just links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to adequately address both of these elements.