# An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x8007005)

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I tried to restore my Windows 10 Computer to a checkpoint but it failed.

[image: Screenshot of error]

The event log has the following Event ID 8210

> An unspecified error occurred during System Restore: (Scheduled Checkpoint). Additional information: 0x80070005.

Other questions about this error were either related to other anti-virus programs or other versions of windows. Others had the same hex-code but a different error message. I tried [one of my solutions](https://superuser.com/a/1207590/302157) to another question that had a different hex code and it didn't work.

I'm running:

```
Windows 10 Pro
Version 1803
OS build 17134.3112
```

I use and have enabled windows defender antivirus. I don't currently have *controlled folder access* (which keeps programs and ransomware from modifying certain folders) enabled. I have *Real-time protection* and *Cloud-delivered protection* enabled.

I tried a different restore point and got the same error.

In the event viewer, I have two identical warnings (spread one second apart) from *Ntfs (Ntfs)* Event ID 134 that occurred some 30 seconds before the second System Restore error event.

The only other event log error is:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
>    and APPID 
>   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
>    to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

I tried disabling Windows-Defender and the restore still failed.

I tried running system restore from advanced startup options (boot menu) but that didn't work either.

`chkdsk` found no problems.

Is there some way to determine what file system restore couldn't access?

Comment: Some other things to try....https://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-system-restore-error-0x80070005/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore to the desired checkpoint by running system restore from within safe-mode.

Here's instructions for booting into safe-mode.

1. Open *Change Advanced Startup Settings* in system settings
2. Click *Restart now*
   [image]
3. *Troubleshoot*
   [image: choose an option]
4. *Advanced options*
   [image: advanced options]
5. *Startup Settings
   [image: startup settings]
6. *Restart*
7. Press <kbd>4</kbd> to enable safe mode
   [image: startup settings]
8. Once windows boots and you login, run system restore (search recovery)

Comment: Safe Mode has been in the Advanced Startup since Windows 8.  This was required due to the hybrid startup that Windows 8+ supports (i.e. the only "negative" of 5 second boot times).