# Windows Update KB4577266 broke WiFi and cannot be uninstalled

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-update

The Windows Update KB4577266 broke my WiFi and I cannot uninstall it.
Before trying to uninstall, I tried the following actions, all unsuccessfully:

- Activating Airplane mode and then deactivating it
- Disabling the WiFi driver in device manager and re-enabling it (cannot update driver, as cannot connect to WiFi)
- Restarting the computer
- Forgetting the network before trying to reconnect (it can see networks, but gives an error when trying to connect to them)
- Using the troubleshooter

I have two Windows Updates from the recent hours:

- KB4579311, which I successfully uninstalled, but it didn't solve my problem after restart
- KB4577266

The problem with KB4577266 is:

1. When I right-click it, it won't response (usually it should show a context-menu with an Uninstall option)
2. When I open a CMD console as an Administrator and run `wusa /uninstall /kb:4577266`, I get the following error message:

   `Windows Update Standalone Installer: Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4577266) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled.`

How can I force Windows to uninstall it?

### "Solution" Summary

1. After the two updates were installed, I couldn't connect to any WiFi network.
2. Tried to uninstall the two updates one by one. Windows refused to uninstall the second update, while uninstalling just the first update didn't solve it.
3. I wanted to restore the system to the point before the two updates were installed, BUT I've already uninstalled one of them, so the ONLY point available for restore was the point before I uninstalled it, i.e., where the two updates had just been installed.
4. I nevertheless ran restore to that point, hoping that having the system running in that point, it would allow me to restore an even earlier point, where I'd get rid of the two updates.
5. After the restore process to the point where the two updates were just installed had been completed, the WiFi was back to work properly, even though the two updates were there. I can't explain why.

Comment: You cannot.  So you will have to diagnose the root cause and find another solution other than uninstalling the update.  You could try using a restore point

Comment: The problem is that I already uninstalled one update - now my restore point is the point before uninstalling that update. The point before the two updates were installed is gone.

Comment: I'm wondering whether restoring to the available point will also restore the restore point it had available then.

Comment: Look at the following "affected users have found this workaround to be effective:"

Type ‘Registry Editor’ in Windows Search
Open it and find: “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet”
Change the “EnableActiveProbing” value from 0 to 1
Click ‘OK’, close the editor
Restart your computer    ... This was the article:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2020/07/21/microsoft-windows-10-upgrade-2004-may-2020-breaks-internet-connections-update-free-windows-10-update/?sh=7b0ce0921e24

Comment: @SomethingSomething - The restore point will essentially uninstall the update. [If you run into an error use this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1181791/system-restore-doesnt-work-on-windows-10/1203440#1203440)

Comment: @SomethingSomething, if all else fails, download the Windows ISO and try installing while keeping your files. Or try another OS, such as Linux... you can test Linux from a live USB without installing, and, if it gets WiFi access, install it dual boot, or stand-alone.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Somehow the restore solved it (I couldn't restore the point before the two updates were installed, but just the point before I uninstalled the first of the two updates)..